# Visual Studio error C2664 when using overloaded methods

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gdi+, overloading

I've got a class to manage pen, colors collections and drawings : NRGraphics :

```
class NRGraphics
{
    ...
    void newPen(std::string name, float epaisseur, Color couleur, DashStyle style);
    void newPen(std::string name, float epaisseur, std::string colorName, DashStyle style);
    ...
}
```

Those are the only methods with that name.
I use most the second in some functions.

Today I was writing a new class, and I had to use the second method, so here it is what I wrote :

```
void NRCell::draw(NRGraphics * drawer)
{
    switch(backgroundStyle)
    {
        case Solid:
            std::string colorName;
            std::string borderPen;
            std::string borderColorName = "pas de couleur";

            try
            {
                colorName = drawer->findColor(color->Red(), color->Green(), color->Blue(), color->Alpha());
            }
            catch(std::exception e)
            {
                colorName  = "R";
                colorName += color->Red();
                colorName += "G";
                colorName += color->Green();
                colorName += "B";
                colorName += color->Blue();
                colorName += "A";
                colorName += color->Alpha();

                drawer->newColor(colorName, color->Red(), color->Green(), color->Blue(), color->Alpha());
            }

            try
            {
                borderColorName = drawer->findColor(
                borderColor->Red(),
                borderColor->Green(),
                borderColor->Blue(),
                borderColor->Alpha());

                borderPen = drawer->findPen(borderColorName, borderSize);
            }
            catch(std::exception e)
            {
                if(borderColorName == "pas de couleur")
                {
                borderColorName  = "R";
                borderColorName += borderColor->Red();
                borderColorName += "G";
                borderColorName += borderColor->Green();
                borderColorName += "B";
                borderColorName += borderColor->Blue();
                borderColorName += "A";
                borderColorName += borderColor->Alpha();

                drawer->newColor(
                  borderColorName,
                  borderColor->Red(),
                  borderColor->Green(),
                  borderColor->Blue(),
                  borderColor->Alpha());
                }

                borderPen  = "Pen_color_";
                borderPen += borderColorName;
                borderPen += "_size_";
                borderPen += borderSize;
                drawer->newPen(borderPen, (float)borderSize, borderColorName, 0);
            }

            drawer->DrawFilledSolidRectangle(
                rect->getPt1()->X(), rect->getPt1()->Y(),
                rect->getPt2()->X(), rect->getPt2()->Y(),
                colorName,
                borderPen,
                borderSize
            );
        break;

    /*case GradientHorizontal:
    break;

    case GradientVertical:
    break;*/
    }
}
```

And here it is what Visual Studio output me when compiling :

```
1>c:\users\md2i\desktop\current\branch\devel\sources\nrgraphicscomponents.cpp(90): error C2664: 'void NRGraphics::newPen(std::string,float,Gdiplus::Color,Gdiplus::DashStyle)' : impossible de convertir le paramètre 3 de 'std::string' en 'Gdiplus::Color'
1>          Aucun opérateur de conversion définie par l'utilisateur disponible qui puisse effectuer cette conversion, ou l'opérateur ne peut pas être appelé
```

Automatic english translation of error message :

```
1>c:\users\md2i\desktop\current\branch\devel\sources\nrgraphicscomponents.cpp(90): error C2664: 'void NRGraphics::newPen(std::string,float,Gdiplus::Color,Gdiplus::DashStyle)' : can not convert parameter 3 from 'std::string' to 'Gdiplus::Color'
1>          No conversion operator defined by the user available that can perform this conversion, or the operator can not be called
```

I'm a bit confused, because when I'm using Visual Studio auto-completion it show me all the overloaded methods.

I don't know what I do wrong.

Thanks for your help

Comment: try clearing out all temporary files and restart VS

Comment: I closed Visual Studio, delete the build folder, this file : project.sdf and the ipch folder. Then restart VS, try building the concerned file : that don't work ; and then I try Rebuild the whole project, that failed too...

Comment: Plz post relevant text in english.

Comment: done, I just use Google Translate.

Comment: The error say's "can't convert std::string to gdiplus::color". So you should check your parameters. Are they in the correct order?

Comment: Yes, they are, I want to call the second overloaded method named newPen where the third parameter is a std::string.

Comment: If you are not changing the strings within the function, declare them as **const std::string&** instead of **std::string**.  It is something to do with the string signatures on the MS compilers - it is picking up the wrong signature.

Comment: I change `newPen` declaration to that : `void newPen(std::string name, float epaisseur, const std::string & colorName, DashStyle style);` and it doesn't work too... What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolve my problem. I post the answer, that could help.

The problem was on the last parameters. The VS compiler can't convert it to `Gdiplus::DashStyle` (which is an enumeration) so it report an error. But not the right error.

So I just had to cast the last value to `Gdiplus::DashStyle` and it work.

---

More information on `Gdiplus::DashStyle` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx